# Calculate area inside country boundaries for top 10

Tags: geospatial, polygon, geopandas, qgis

Using country boundaries, I wish to calculate area of the polygons inside countries. For example; calculate area of large water bodies inside a country polygon to estimate the top 10 countries with the largest area of water bodies.

Some lakes are trans-national, and can be excluded in the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood your question.
Do you ask how to calculate a polygon area?

If so, and I'm assuming your area is placed on an x and y axis plane, it should be pretty simple:

First of all, make sure you have all the area vertex by their order. Then calculate:

abs(*(x1y2 - x2y1) + (x2y3 - x3y2) + .... + (xny1 - x1yn)*) and *divide it all by 2*.

[The "abs" mean you should get a positive result even if it calculates out as negative.]

Make sure xn is the x coordinate of vertex n, yn is the y coordinate of the nth vertex, etc.
Good Luck!

Comment: in `geooandas`, GeoDataFrames have an `area` method, so the question like more about appropriately filter the data based on spatial relationships to other entities mentioned.